# sfValidatorDoctrineUnique fails on capital letters

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've setup a post validator in my symfony form to stop duplication of primary keys.

A primary key is a two-character string in this instance. Code used to validate:

```
$this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array(
  'model' => 'Manufacturers',
  'column' => 'id',
  'primary_key' => 'id'
)));
```

The primary key is uppercase (for example AU). Bizarrely the post validator triggers successfully is lowercase 'au' is entered into the field (i.e. stops it from going to the database and triggering a 500 integrity constraint error), but if entered correctly as 'AU' it doesn't seem to notice the duplication.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't really understand the question. If you're asking "Is the sfValidatorDoctrineUnique() case sensitive?" then the answer is "yes", because the database can also be case sensitive.

Comment: @Blowski: I think the OP is saying the constraint triggers when the code is not exactly the same (`au` vs `AU`), but it does not when it is exactly the same (`AU` vs `AU`) which is indeed.

Comment: What collation are you using for the id column?

Answer (score 3):

That's not a symfony sfDoctrineValidator issue. All this validor does is to search your database for an existing record. If you are using a "_ci" (case-insensitive) collation (are you using mysql?) the search returns nothing - the validator is fooled.

Then when you insert the duplicate, you get a exception from the database. Try to change the collation of your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

(you should tell doctrine to do it for you:

```
MyTable:
  options: { collate: utf8_bin, charset: utf8 }
```

)